# Отклоненная правка ответа. Правка добавляет снипет в ответ

Tags: обсуждение, отклонённые-правки

Отвечал на вопрос [Показать больше/скрыть для записей на angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566031/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-angular). Дал свой ответ. Увидел ответ от другого участника, ответ тоже верный. Но в ответе от другого участника не было ссылки на *fiddle* или сниппета.

Ответ мне понравился, думаю, он имеет право на жизнь. Решил добавить снипет, для улучшения ответа. [Мою правку по добавлению сниппета не приняли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/106998).

Согласно справки:

Основные причины для редактирования:

- исправить грамматические или орфографические ошибки;
- прояснить суть сообщения, не изменяя его;
- исправить мелкие погрешности или, если информация устарела, дополнить или обновить;
- **дополнить ссылками или указать полезные ресурсы по теме.**

Кажется, под последний пункт попадает добавление сниппета.

---

После ответа от @D-Side, решил поправить правку путем добавления снипета, не меняя в ответе автора ни строчки. Вот эта правка [Правка ТОЛЬКО по добавлению сниппета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/107038).

Вопрос все еще остается актуальным.

**Вопрос**: Добавление снипета в ответ\вопрос не является улучшением ответа\вопроса?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Всё упирается в простой вопрос:

#### Сохранено ли намерение автора ответа?

Сходу посмотрев на правку, я бы сказал, что **нет**, поскольку в ответе присутствовал (пусть и в неявном виде) **дифф** для кода в вопросе, с обозначениями, предложенными автором и понятными ему. **Вы этот момент сломали**. Вроде бы мелочь, но автору гораздо проще осознать ответ в его же терминах.

Я вижу два возможных продуктивных исхода такой ситуации:

1. **Если делаете правку, не убирайте то, что там было**:
   *Ничего не убирая,* допишите, мол, "вот автономный исполняемый пример <сниппет>". Отклонять такое будет уже меньше причин.
2. **Оставьте свой ответ:**
   А почему нет? Если ту же самую идею вы можете изложить более доходчиво, вы сами заслужили репутацию за хорошее изложение.

Ну и предлагая правку, надо понимать, что её будут проверять люди, в том числе не знающие Angular, для которых эта правка просто выглядит полным переписыванием ответа и напрашивается на отклонение. Пока у вас нет 2000 репутации, вам будут "слегка не доверять". А когда будет — ваши правки будут приниматься без рассмотрения.

Comment: Я свою идею изложил и ее приняли как верный ответ. Но другой ответ тоже верный. Я понял, надо добавлять сниппет *не ломая*, просто дополнив. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал по Вашему совету, не меняя оригинальный текст\код автора добавить сниппет. Правка по добавлению сниппета не прошла. Видимо, добовление сниппета сообщество не считает улучшением поста))

Comment: Я эту правку и отклонил так как вы переписали ответ не стоит вносить изменения в сам ответ.

Comment: Мне уже объяснили, что улучшать код\текст автора не надо. Поэтому я создал другую правку, где *только добавил сниппет*, не меняя в тексте автора ни одной буквы. Данную правку тоже не приняли.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko этого я уже объяснить сходу не могу ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @D-side а вы не могли предоставить ссылку на отмененную правку. Я найти ее не знаю, как.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в профиле, "все действия", "правки".

Comment: К сожалению, на "все действия"->"правки" показываются только мои правки, которые я вносил в собственные ответы. Возможно, показываются также принятые правки, внесенные в чужие ответы. А вот не принятые правки, внесенные в чужие ответы не показываются.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko упс, мимо. "Все действия" -> "предложения".

Comment: К сожалению, правка тоже была отменена с сообщением *Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения. Даже правки, которые призваны изменить сообщение в корне, должны быть выполнены с соблюдением идей автора сообщения.*

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko человеческий фактор